# Documentation for parsing raw-socket data with struct iphdr and ip.h

Tags: c, ip, glibc, raw-sockets

I am looking for documentation on how to use the GNU LibC's raw socket API on Linux.

So far I have read the following man pages:

```
man 7 ip
man 7 raw
man 7 socket
```

Looking at the `netinet/ip.h` header I find there is a `struct iphdr` definition. However, neither in the [GNU LibC Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_mono/libc.html), nor in any of the above man pages I could find any information about how to use this API. Specifically, how to parse an IP package received via a SOCK_RAW socket into an iphdr struct and how to access the individual bit fields.

Looking at the header I see that it distinguishes between endianess for the *version* and *header length* fields, but I fail to understand how the other fields can be extracted, such
as:

- priority and type of service (6 and 2 bits)
- flags and fragment offset (3 and 13 bits)

If there are macros available for parsing these fields then I would assume they are documented somewhere? Where can I find such documentation.

I would also like to verify my assumption that I can simply use a `char *buffer` received through `recvfrom` and assign that through a cast to a `struct iphdr` like this:

```
char *buffer;
recvfrom (raw_socket_fd, buffer, ...);

struct iphdr* ipPacket;
ipPacket = (struct iphdr*) buffer;
```

Either I missed something or this header is not documented anywhere?

My question is **mainly about where this is documented**. However, a code sample on how to parse the above mentioned bit-fields would also be welcome.

Comment: The [IPv4 header is well documented](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4#Header). I also suggest you read the RFC's (the standard documents).

Comment: I have read that Wiki Page. I have already written a program that manually parses a raw socket package and extracts the individual bit fields. That worked fine. My question is specifically about using the `ip.h` header of libc.

Comment: After the assignment `ipPacket = (struct iphdr*) buffer;` you have your structure all ready. The member fields in the structure corresponds to the documented fields of the header. There's really not much more to say. Perhaps that you should try and look at other examples, there are several thousand examples all over the Internet.

Comment: So the answer is that the `ip.h` header is undocumented and users are supposed to find random examples on the Internet to see how the header and the ip and iphdr structs are used? How does that fit into usual answers that one should read the manual (RTFM?)?

Comment: Raw socket is an advanced topic. It is assumed that programmers needing this header will be able to read the existing documentation about TCP/IP, and be able to read the header file and the structure itself, and then be able to puzzle it together themselves. Being able to do that is an important aspect or programming and being a good programmer. The documentation is the code and the existing documents and examples.

Comment: The wiki page is not documentation.  The question is specifically about unserializing `struct iphdr`.  Examples on the Internet seem to imply you can just `memcpy` a raw buffer containing an IP header into a `struct iphdr` and the fields are all required to properly line up, but the question is about *where this is explicitly documented*